# Phone will randomly crash, then only loads to boot loader

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, boot-loop, bootloader

I rooted my Samsung-sm-g930a (Galaxy s7 AT&T)
And after I did, the *VOLTE* showed up... I thought nothing of it because it is **Voice Over LTE** but a week after I did that when i tried to open an app it closed the app 2 seconds later (almost immediately) and if I restart my phone it gets stuck at the AT&T logo I can boot it into recovery and reset the device, this fixes it temporarily then 3 days later it does it Agian. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What's the said app that's force closing? Is your phone doing an update or something? Specifics! What your experiencing is called a boot loop where the phone is stuck at the boot animation. I don't know why it would do that after three days but an app or mod you installed can be causing it.

Comment: give it the stock rom

Comment: @JCTechie The only root app I had installed was **Super SU** and I did not _"mod"_ the phone or Anything... The only thing I did was go into /data/data/com.505Games.TerrariaPaid and I replaced a few of the worlds. Corrupted things in a game wouldn't screw up the whole phone would it? And, it's all apps doing it, besides settings and chrome

Comment: @Donovan_D I think the easiest solution for you is to factory reset your phone, and re-do the root process. It sounds to me that something got messed up when rooting, and you need to start over. You can backup your contacts and game saves with google or get an app that does that for you (titanium backup can restore your app data)

Comment: @JCTechie I did a factory data reset, it still does it 3-7 days later

Comment: @Donovan_D does the factory reset have root? Is it unrooted and crashing? That's probably a bigger problem, try downloading a stock rom for your phone from xda-developers and flash it through recovery.

Comment: @JCTechie when I do the factory reset cpu-z says I still have root, but I can't use it. Another root checker said that root was not properly gained. My system status is now _"Custom"_ And on startup it shows [_"Custom"_ with a unlocked padlock](https://www.mcpsb.co/Android/Custom/Images/Custom.png) that's not my phone but it's similar

Comment: @Donovan_D that's very strange, I recommend that you download this stock rom from XDA-Developers. Follow the instructions (i'm not sure what "type" of S7 you have, if that's really a thing, but check that that's the correct phone before installing the stock rom :)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/development/6-0-1-s7-stock-rom-v1-bloat-script-mods-t3423409

Comment: @Donovan_D that rom includes root BTW

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that something wrong has happened with your rom. Since factory resetting has not fixed the issue, the next step is to restore the stock rom. Here's a link to the stock rom for the Samsung Galaxy S7:

Edit: New link (from OP): https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s7/how-to/firmware-stock-sm-g930a-pb5-odin-files-t3411468

(Includes Root)

Comment: -1: you offered a "stock" ROM for the wrong model (G930F uses Exynos, G930A uses Snapdragon) that would wreak havoc if actually flashed, and it's a stock-**based** ROM flashed from a custom recovery, not a real stock ROM flashed via Odin, so it's of little use for fault recovering.

Comment: @andy yan woops sorry I don't own a Samsung so... What's the link to the correct stock rom?

Comment: I just looked it up - weird that both SamMobile and Samsung-Updates don't offer firmware for this particular model. Some over at [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s7/help/g930aucs4apk1-t3543174) does seem to have one, so editing this in is at least better than not. I'll retract the -1 after your edit.

Comment: @JCTechie I think I found it here:  https://forum.xda-developers.com/att-galaxy-s7/how-to/firmware-stock-sm-g930a-pb5-odin-files-t3411468

Answer (score 0):

I ever faced a situation like this where my phone load until the Samsung logo and that's it. What I did was installing a stock rom in to my Samsung and it did fix my phone. You can visit the web of cyanogen to see if your phone model is listed there.